# Adding a slash causes error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, expressionengine

Here is my rewrite code:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase "/"
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
    RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.whatever.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This is for an expression engine site.  If I take these 2 lines out, the site works fine:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
    RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.whatever.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Those are the lines I added to add a trailing slash to any URL if it doesn't have one, to avoid duplicate indexing in Google.  It results in this error in my log file:
Request exceeded the l                                                                                                             "Limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error"

I assume its not processing the RewriteCond right and entering an infinite loop.  Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the principle: after any rewrite, the entire ruleset is processed from the beginning. The `[L]` flag does not prevent this; it controls whether the rule is the last in the current run.

In this case the problem is the last rule. It rewrites anything like this:

```
foo → index.php/foo → index.php/index.php/foo → ...
```

When you remove the two lines, this rule gets the `!-f` and `!-d` conditions attached, which prevents the loop.

From the grouping of the lines it looks like you want to attach those two conditions to all following rules. You can't do that, but instead you can attach the opposite conditions to a rule that will stop processing:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: Good explanation, the [OR] turned out to be unnecessary though and in fact made it break, but, changing the order up to where the !-f and !-d lines were right before index.php line made it work like a charm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my ExpressionEngine .htaccess which removes trailing slashes, not sure if you have a preference but I think it looks better without them.

```
RewriteEngine on

# get rid of trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# no plain index.php either
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)$ / [L,NC,R=301]

# rewrite index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(images|system|themes|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Rewrite logging (`RewriteLogLevel 3` or so should do it), and most like you'll see the request getting bounced back and forth between

```
 www.whatever.com/blah
 www.whatever.com/blah/
 www.whatever.com/blah
 www.whatever.com/blah/
 www.whatever.com/blah
 www.whatever.com/blah/
 etc....
```

Comment: I'd guess the trailing slash in the alternating group in the 'bad' rewriterule. Look at the rewritelog (and bump up the levels until you can see what it's doing internally).